# Memory semantics of dladdr() out parameter

Tags: c, dynamic-linking, dladdr

What are the memory semantics of `dladdr()`?

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>

int dladdr(void *addr, Dl_info *info);

typedef struct {
    const char *dli_fname;  /* Pathname of shared object that contains address */
    void       *dli_fbase;  /* Base address at which shared object is loaded */
    const char *dli_sname;  /* Name of symbol whose definition overlaps addr */
    void       *dli_saddr;  /* Exact address of symbol named in dli_sname */
} Dl_info;
```

From reading the man page, it's unclear whether `dli_fname`:

- Points to a constant string and never needs to be freed
- Points to a heap array, with the user responsible for deleting it
- Points to global array (probably not, since it claims to be reentrant)

I suppose the same question applies to `dli_sname`, but I suspect that indeed points to a constant string (the symbol itself).

Is the user responsible for deleting `dli_fname` returned by `dladdr()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These strings are valid until the object is unloaded via `dlclose` (either directly or indirectly).

The `const char *` conveys that the string must not be freed by the `dladdr` caller because `free` expects a `void *`, not a `const void *`.